# Unitary Bose gas

Tags: bose-einstein-condensate, unitarity, bosons

A unitary Bose gas (more about it [[here]](http://arxiv.org/abs/1302.1792)) is defined to occur when the scattering length diverges.

What I don't understand, however, is *which* quantity/matrix is actually unitary?

I mean, they could have called it "divergent", "critical" etc. but they named it "unitary", which suggests it has a connection with the physical meaning of [unitarity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unitarity_%28physics%29).

Comment: so there is no connection whatsoever to that? Why not choosing a different word then :) ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The term *unitary gas* refers to the regime where the scattering cross-section is the largest possible, under the unitarity constraint: the scattering matrix (i.e. the time-evolution operator) must be unitary. The terminology derives from *unitarity-limited*. One also refers to the regime of maximal cross-section simply as *unitarity*; for example, "the scattering length diverges at unitarity". For $s$-wave scattering, which is the most relevant at low temperatures, the total cross-section at unitarity is
$$ \sigma(k) = \frac{4\pi}{k^2},$$
where $\hbar k$ is the momentum of the scattered particles.

Comment: That makes way more sense.

Comment: Thanks. But isn't the time-evolution operator always unitary? Why would it be a constaint here?

Comment: @SuperCiocia If $\sigma(k)$ were any larger than $4\pi/k^2$ then the time evolution operator would not be unitary. Hence there is a physical constraint on the size of the scattering cross-section, because the time evolution operator is in fact unitary.

Comment: Thanks. What's the relation between σ and the time-evolution operator?

Comment: @SuperCiocia Scattering is a kind of time evolution: an incoming particle evolves to a new state with a different momentum and energy. An explanation of how to derive $\sigma$ from the time evolution operator requires at least one substantial chapter of an elementary QM text, e.g. Landau & Lifshitz or Sakurai. You will also find all sorts of resources by Googling (e.g. "elastic scattering in quantum mechanics"): this is one of the most important and well studied problems in quantum dynamics.